# Cocoa HUD window - how to turn off topmost?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I've wrote some small cocoa app and it's main window has HUD style.
The problem is - when I set HUD style Interface Builder automatically also sets Utility style - which make the main window topmost (always visible over every other windows). Is there a way to get HUD style panel/window but without making it topmost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out - there's a pretty simple solution for my topmost problem:

```
[hudPanel setLevel: NSNormalWindowLevel];
```

Makes it act like a normal window that isn't topmost.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't do it in IB, you'll have to do it programmatically. In this case, that means creating the window programmatically. (You'll want to move the window's views into a separate top-level view in the nib, and set that view as the programmatically-created window's content view.)

You should also [file a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/), as it doesn't seem from [the NSPanel documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSHUDWindowMask) that the HUD style necessarily implies the utility-window nature.

Comment: I read a little bit more documentation about NSPanel from your link - I would call this HUD + Utility checkboxes a bug (but I bet they did it on purpose) and I can create HUD window programmatically but it's square (without rounded corners) and it seems that you can't set HUD window that has close button and window title.
I did custom HUD-like button already so probably I will have to make custom window subclass that looks like HUD panel..

Comment: You should be able to add the style masks for a title and close button.